# Change the for loop with lambda(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

Is it possible to do the same using Lambda

```
for (int i = 0; i < objEntityCode.Count; i++)
{
    options.Attributes[i] = new EntityCodeKey();
    options.Attributes[i].EntityCode = objEntityCode[i].EntityCodes;
    options.Attributes[i].OrganizationCode = Constants.ORGANIZATION_CODE;
}
```

I mean to say to rewrite the statement using lambda. I tried with

```
Enumerable.Range(0,objEntityCode.Count-1).Foreach(i=> { 
    options.Attributes[i] = new EntityCodeKey(); 
    options.Attributes[i].EntityCode = objEntityCode[i].EntityCodes; 
    options.Attributes[i].OrganizationCode = Constants.ORGANIZATION_CODE; }
);
```

but not working 
I am using C#3.0

Comment: I mean to say to rewrite the statement using lambda.
I tried withEnumerable.Range(0,objEntityCode.Count-1).Foreach(i=>
{ options.Attributes[i] = new EntityCodeKey(); 
options.Attributes[i].EntityCode = objEntityCode[i].EntityCodes; 
    options.Attributes[i].OrganizationCode = Constants.ORGANIZATION_CODE;
}); but not working

Comment: Why do you want to do it using lambdas? If your structure relies on the index then it doesn't lend itself to a List.ForEach() structure, and FWIW, loops are a core part of the programming language...how does it improve your program by *not* using them?

Comment: It does not deserve the try. It is possible to rewrite it using lambdas... just for educational purposes

Comment: Yes ur right. I basically wanted to say that only. However, I solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you can make it simpler with object initializers, to start with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objEntityCode.Count; i++)
{
    options.Attributes[i] = new EntityCodeKey
    {
        EntityCode = objEntityCode[i].EntityCodes,
        OrganizationCode = Constants.ORGANIZATION_CODE
    };
}
```

I would probably leave it at that though... there's currently no `ForEach` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` - and for [good reasons](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx), although I know it's not a universally held opinion ;)

In this case, you'd *still* need to know `i` in order to set `options.Attributes[i]` - unless you could set the whole of `options.Attributes` in one go, of course... without knowing about the types involved, it's pretty hard to advise further.

If `options.Attributes` is a writable property (e.g. an array), you could use:

```
options.Attributes = objEntityCode.Select(code => new EntityCodeKey
    {
        EntityCode = code.EntityCodes,
        OrganizationCode = Constants.ORGANIZATION_CODE
    }).ToArray();
```

If `options.Attributes` is *actually* just a property which returns a type with an indexer, that won't work.

Comment: Sir, what is wrng in the below
Enumerable.Range(0, objEntityCode.Count - 1).Select(i =>
{ options.Attributes[i] = new EntityCodeKey
   { EntityCode = objEntityCode[i].EntityCodes
     , OrganizationCode = Constants.ORGANIZATION_CODE };

   }).ToArray();
Throwing error
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Your lambda expression doesn't return anything. It's just a statement.  That doesn't really help a Select projection... The other thing that's "wrong" with it is that it introduces a whole heap of stuff for no reason. LINQ is meant to make code *simpler*, not more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, objEntityCode.Count - 1).ToList().ForEach(i => 
                {
                    options.Attributes[i] = new EntityCodeKey(); 
                    options.Attributes[i].EntityCode = objEntityCode[i].EntityCodes;
                    }
                );
```

Comment: I'll add the same comment I made on your question: Why do you want to do it like this? How is it any better than explicitly writing the loop?

Comment: Sir, I am learning LINQ and LAMBDA.... henceforth I try to write those statements. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, objEntityCode.Count - 1).ToList().ForEach(i => 
                {
                    options.Attributes[i] = new EntityCodeKey
                    {
                         EntityCode = objEntityCode[i].EntityCodes
                         , OrganizationCode = Constants.ORGANIZATION_CODE  
                    }; 

                }
             );
```